# Python-way time series transform

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm, numpy

Good day!
There is the following time series dataset:

```
Time Value
1     1
2     1
3     1
4     2
5     2
6     2
7     2
8     3
9     3
10    4
11    4
12    5
```

I need to split and group data by value like this:

```
Value   Time start, Time end
1          1        3
2          4        7
3          8        9
4          10       11
5          12       12
```

How to do it fast and in the most functional programming style on python? Various libraries can be used for example pandas, numpy.

Comment: `Various libraries can be used for example pandas, numpy.` - right, and what did you choose and tried?

Comment: @buran, I think the pandas is the most suitable for this purpose. But I'm looking for the most beautiful option. If I succeed myself, then I will answer the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with pandas:

```
df.groupby('Time')['Value'].agg(['min','max'])
```

Answer (score 0):

first get the count of Values

```
result = df.groupby('Value').agg(['count'])
result.columns = result.columns.get_level_values(1) #drop multi-index
result

       count
Value       
1          3
2          4
3          2
4          2
5          1
```

then cumcount to get time start

```
s = df.groupby('Value').cumcount()
result["time start"] = s[s == 0].index.tolist()
result

       count  time start
Value                   
1          3           0
2          4           3
3          2           7
4          2           9
5          1          11
```

finally,

```
result["time start"] += 1
result["time end"] = result["time start"] + result['count'] - 1
result

       count  time start  time end
Value                             
1          3           1         3
2          4           4         7
3          2           8         9
4          2          10        11
5          1          12        12
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use pandas for this:

Solution:

```
data = {'Time': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12],
    'Value':  [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5]
    }
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns= ['Time', 'Value'])
res = df.groupby('Value').agg(['min', 'max'])
f_res = res.rename(columns = {'min': 'Start Time', 'max': 'End Time'}, inplace = False)
print(f_res)
```

Output:

```
            Time         
      Start Time End Time
Value                    
1              1        3
2              4        7
3              8        9
4             10       11
5             12       12
```